# New construction - How to address WRB/Stucco around Garage opening?

Tags: garage, stucco

First time poster... please go easy on me.

I'm building an ADU/small house and framers have finished up. I'm doing 90% of the rest myself including WRB and rainscreen install, but not the actual stucco. The framers left a tall curb on either side the garage opening I have no idea what to do with. I'm used to older homes where the stucco is basically level with the driveway (not ideal, I know). The stucco guy says he can come down 1/2" to 2" below the plywood sheathing. But, that still leaves a 3"-4" gap gap below this point to the bottom of the garage opening - see small circled area below. As I plan to install WRB soon, I'm looking for guidance here.

What are my options for that small section at the bottom? Anyone have any pics of similar garage openings? And with the WRB (Blueskin in my case) should this simply wrap around the corner, overlapping the flashing tape? (Stucco guys will do their own 2 layers of paper per code)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Perhaps the new standard is doing something with that area, but FWIW, I have never seen much done with that portion of the foundation, other than applying stone veneer directly to the surface. You could cover it with 1/2" rigid foam board bonded with thinset that is used with the EIFS system??? It is just a guess, may not be practical. Then the stucco guys might go over it?

Comment: I'm in agreement with Jack.  I really don't understand why the stucco guys wouldn't handle that themselves.  In my area, it is common for them to do so.

Comment: Just another mention, in areas where termite infestation is present, is where I am from, it is required by code to leave the foundation exposed to daylight to hinder the  termites from easily entering the framing.  My suggestion would not be code since it would allow a protected path for termites.